# How to set OLEObject name using a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I rename an OLEObject?

The object is embedded and the oname variable works when used in the other lines but the `.name` command will not work. There is no error.

```vb
Public Sub insertFiles()
Dim newObject As Object
Dim oname As String
Dim CheckName As String
 
CheckName = UserForm1.MultiPage2.SelectedItem.Caption
oname = CheckName & "_" & "Evidence" & "_" & UserForm1.ProjectName.Value & "_" & Format(Date, "ddmmmyyyy")

Worksheets("Emails").Activate
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Set Rng = ActiveCell
Rng.RowHeight = 70

On Error Resume Next

fpath = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files,*.*", Title:="Select file")
If LCase(fpath) = "false" Then Exit Sub
    
If UserForm1.ProjectName.Value <> Empty Then
       
    ActiveCell.Value = "."

    ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fpath, _
      Link:=False, _
      DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
      IconFileName:="Outlook.msg", _
      IconIndex:=1, _
      IconLabel:=extractFileName(fpath)).Name = oname
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oname
    UserForm1.Attached1.Value = oname
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("B35").Value = oname

    Call UserForm1.Tickbox

    UserForm1.LablePIA.Visible = True
    UserForm1.Attached1.Visible = True
    UserForm1.View.Visible = True
    UserForm1.Deleteemail.Visible = True

    MsgBox "Attachment uploaded"
  
Else
    MsgBox "Project Name must be input before emails can be uploaded"
End If

End Sub

Public Function extractFileName(filePath)
    For i = Len(filePath) To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(filePath, i, 1) = "\" Then
        extractFileName = Mid(filePath, i + 1, Len(filePath) - i + 1)
        Exit Function
        End If
    Next

End Function
```

**Solution:**
The string variable contained too many characters, apparently the max is 35.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next` and run the code. The error message may tell you what the issue is :)

Comment: Thanks Scott, the error message is  "unable to set the Name property of the OLEObject class".

Answer (score 2):

OLEObject names cannot exceed 35 characters (presumably unless you use a class module etc!).

Comment: I can manually set the oleobject's name in the selection pane to as many characters as I want. Why is this a limitation in vba?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
Dim Obj As OLEObject

set Obj = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=fpath, _
    Link:=False, _
    DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
    IconFileName:="Outlook.msg", _
    IconIndex:=1, _
   IconLabel:=extractFileName(fpath))

Obj.name = oname
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I've figured out the problem, the string variable contained too many characters, apparently the max is 35! That's 2 day's of my life I'll never get back! I knew it should have been working but couldn't figure out what was wrong!